# Why is strlen slower when I return its results from a method?

Tags: c++, string, strlen

I am writing a string class in my spare time for C++. There is a good reason that I'm not just using `std::string` but that's not what this is about, trust me when I say that `std::string` is not the answer here.

In my header only string class (UString) I have:

```
inline size_t Length()
{
    return strlen(rawString);
}
```

When I profile this I get:

```
String size retrieval times

CString:        53
UString:        605
std::string:    71
```

My code to time the function calls is:

```
timespec ts;
timespec ts2;

const char* s1 = "Hello World";
UString     s2 = "Hello World";
std::string s3 = "Hello World";

std::cout << "String size retrieval times" << std::endl << std::endl;

std::cout << "CString: \t";
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
strlen(s1);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts2);
std::cout << ts2.tv_nsec - ts.tv_nsec << std::endl;

std::cout << "UString: \t";
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
s1.Length();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts2);
std::cout << ts2.tv_nsec - ts.tv_nsec << std::endl;

std::cout << "std::string: \t";
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
s3.size();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts2);
std::cout << ts2.tv_nsec - ts.tv_nsec << std::endl;
```

When I change my Length method to:

```
inline size_t Length()
{
  strlen(rawString);
  return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
String size retrieval times

CString:        57
UString:        80
std::string:    88
```

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with G++ 4.9.2 
I am compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 ustringtest.cpp -o stringtest -lrt`

Any ideas? I'm very confused. My guess is it has something to do with return types and I'm casting something implicitly when I don't mean to but I was pretty sure that `st

Comment: Isn't it totally obvious? In one case the compiler knows the length already, in the other it doesn't. In one case, it already knows that the string is aligned on an allocation boundary, on others just on a byte boundary. Also, you should measure the time of no operation at all for sensible comparison.

Comment: Your compiler is probably just optimizing the second case to just `return 0;`, hence not performing the work.

Comment: You can't effectively benchmark single run of such microscopic function.

Comment: For proper mini benchmarking see e.g. https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius

Comment: It's hard to trust you when you say that `std::string` is "not the answer". `std::string` has been optimized to death. A lot of folks, me included, think that the amount of work that has been poured into standard libraries warrants more humility. Despite the (IMO) valid question, the preface is probably what got you downvoted.

Comment: It would be strange for `std::string` to be the answer when I was trying to write my own string class out of curiosity / for learning purposes. I guess I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the compiler can determine that the result of a function like `strlen` will only be used in certain ways, it may substitute other code which will be sufficient for such purposes.  For example, if code were to say

```
if (strlen(p) >= 2) ...
```

a compiler could legitimately substitute

```
if (p[0] && p[1]) ...
```

since it would be true in precisely the same cases as the original.  Likewise, if a function said...

```
return strlen("fred12345");
```

a compiler could legitimately substitute

```
return 9;
```

If a function says

```
return strlen(p);
```

however, then unless the compiler can make inferences about what `p` might point to or what might be done with the result, it must invoke code that searches characters starting at `p` until it finds a zero byte.

Comment: It seems to be some sort of compiler magic like you're suggesting.